# Where do I find an interactive 3D model of the human anatomy?

Tags: anatomy

For medical students and more generally for learning purposes, an open-source website with a 3D human body model, in which we can "navigate" (zoom and move/walk), a little bit like a "Google Streetview / Maps" user interface would be very useful.

Where to find such a resource?

Example of use case: I find it quite difficult to understand how pharynx/larynx/esophagus/mouth cavity/etc. are linked, and being able to "walk" in this zone in a 3D mode would be very insightful for learning purposes.

Comment: Are you a medical or biology student? If not, what level of details do you expect?

Comment: @Jan I'm interested for a high level of details indeed (targeted to medical or biology student)

Comment: I don't think there are any free 3D interactive videos available online - it needs to be a software that enables you to "walk through," anyway. This is a random example, looks promising: https://www.visiblebody.com/anatomy-and-physiology-apps/human-anatomy-atlas , it's 25$, which is surprisingly cheap if you ask me. This is not an option?

Comment: I'm trying https://human.biodigital.com/view?id=production%2FmaleAdult%2Fcroup&lang=fr since 30 minutes and it seems quite close to what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that and read some praising comments.

Comment: Hi @Basj, welcome to this site. Good question. Please incorporate the extra details that you described in the comments (student) into your question. Also please change the title to a real question instead, something like: "Where do I find an interactive 3D model of the human anatomy?" then you'll have my upvote.

Comment: @BobOrtiz Thank you for your comment, I just edited!

Answer (score 5):

I like the 3D atlases of https://www.openanatomy.org/atlas-pages/.

You can remove anatomic structures and transact the body as if you're looking at CT-scanning images. They are great if you also want to understand the relation between the 3D-anatomy and CT-images. And best of all, it is completely open source.

---

Here you can see an example of their thorax model. I removed the lungs such that observing the heart is easier.

[image: Heart example]

Answer (score 1):

I'll update this answer if I find new useful resources.

I'm now trying this website: https://human.biodigital.com/view?id=production%2FmaleAdult%2Fmale_region_head_07&lang=fr

and it helped me a little bit to understand the laryngopharynx zone. The navigation is 3D (pan / zoom).